# How to add a link to logo using flexdashboard?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I added a logo to my dashboard following the [flexdashboard doc page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#appearance). Now I'd like to be able to click on the logo and be re-directed to an external page.

I know that you can hyperlink an image with r-markdown with something like:

```
[![alt text](path to image)](web link to website)
```

I'm just struggling to integrate that into the logo in the navigation bar of the flexdashboard. Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks!

I added the logo with these lines:

```
---
title: "My Report"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    css: style.css
    logo: my-logo.png
---
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to alter the logo in the loading process using jQuery. Add these lines underneath your YAML header:

```
<script>
$('.navbar-logo').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com">');
</script>
```

We simply select the HTML element that is part of the class `navbar-logo` and wrap an hyperlink tag around it.

If you want the external website to open in a new tab, add `target=_blank`to the `a` element:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target=_blank>
```

Comment: I don't have vote privileges yet, but this answer solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: if you have brand also, then do the following `<script>
$('.navbar-logo').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com">');
$('.navbar-brand').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com">');
</script>`